# Trim leading slashes using only a batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

For where I work my hands are tied on what I can use in order to do what I want.

What I need to do is create a `.bat` that does a `net view` and outputs it to a `.txt` and remove the leading slashes from the output.

Getting the net view to a file is the easy part but removing the leading slashes is what I am having an issues with.

Not sure if it will matter but the naming system that my company uses is *#####-XX-##*

I have looked around quite a bit and have not been able to find a way to easily do this.

EDIT: Powershell is also something that could be used if someone has a script for that.

Comment: If you do a C# application you can call a `Process` then pipe-the-data into an `XML or Text Format` to manipulate.

Comment: Right, but as I said will not be able to do that here.

Comment: leading slashes from what? Example please. Command line please. More info would help to help ...

Comment: When you do a "net view" the out put is the name of each computer no the network with the leading slashes. To get that to a file I just do a simple "net view >> c:\temp\netview.txt" If the computer name is 12345-ab-01 it will output it to the line as //12345-ab-01, I would like to remove the two leading slashes.

Comment: Why can't you use an actual application; or better yet why can't you use WMI-Powershell? Powershell will easily do that.

Comment: I have never done much with powershell, so I haven't looked into how to do it there to much. Using powershell is something I am allowed to use. My boss has limited what I am allowed to use. There is not a good reason for this limt its just how it is for me to keep my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
net view | select-string '^\\\\([^\\\s]+)' | foreach-object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
} | out-file netview.txt
```

Bill

Answer (score 0):

CMD (replace `%m` with `%%m` for running this in a batch file):

```
for /f "delims=\ tokens=*" %m in ('net view ^| findstr /r "^\\\\"') do (
  echo %m
) >out.txt
```

PowerShell:

```
net view | select-string '^\\\\' -AllMatches `
  | % { $_ -replace '^\\\\', '' } >out.txt
```