# Trim output of command

Tags: powershell, batch-processing

When I run the `net view` command, it will output similar to the following:

```
\\C66423
\\C66424
\\C66425
\\C66426
\\C66427
\\C66428
\\C66429
\\C66430
\\C66432
\\C66433
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible to trim out the `\\` before each computer name?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794831/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794831/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
<new view command here> | ForEach-Object {$_.TrimStart('\')}
```

Comment: I like this, is there a way to only grab the computer name? Example: it pulls in c66433 and trim it so it displays nothing after that last 3.

Comment: I don't think that removes the trailing spaces after the names. It would seem a regex might be a better fit.

Comment: @Aaron this answers your exact question, but what you really want is this - http://poshcode.org/882

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794831/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794831/).

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('net view') do (
 set "string=%%a"
 echo !string:~2!
)
```

should do the trick (untested)

Comment: Tested, and it works. Note that `net view` will output `The command completed successfully.` when completed, and so this script, what could be confusingly to some, outputs the letter `e`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Magoo's answer but without the need for string manipulation, and therefore delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=\" %%a in ('net view') do echo %%a
```

You could also add `skip=2` to the for command to remove the first couple of lines of output - which is:

```
Server Name            Remark
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Here is something interesting.. is it possible to have it remove the two "\\" and also eliminate any while space after the last digit or letter? I find that my other script does not like extra space after the last digit in the computer name.

Comment: In my example, `%%a` will not contain any white space.

Comment: I get an error when I paste that into powershell: At line:1 char:4
+ for /f "delims=\" %%a in ('net view') do echo %%a
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

Comment: You included the batch-file tag and did not specify you only wanted Powershell answers. You might want to update the question.